# react hook: react router param change, but view is not re rendering from start

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using `react hook` and `react-router-dom 5.0`. I have URLs like `'/home/123', '/home/234'` and the router definition will be

```
<Switch>
<Route index route exact path='/home/:id' render={(match) => <component match={match}/> 
</Switch>.
```

Whenever I change the URL, the view is not reloading to zero. But `:id` getting changed in the URL. I am not using any `browserouter` on the top of `<switch>`

Can you please suggest the correct syntax ?

Comment: You are _not_ using a BrowserRouter? React Router needs a router to work.

Comment: Ok. I tried but none of the components are loaded. Let me try again. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a browserrouter. When Click the URL, it is working fine. but when I click the menu. It is changing in the URL, but view is not rendering according to the params. kindly help.

Comment: Did you try to log the `match` to see wether it's defined or not?